# Use files from different folders in a function in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have a main folder like this:

```
mainf/01/streets/streets.shp
mainf/02/streets/streets.shp    #normal files
mainf/03/streets/streets.shp
...
```

and another main folder like this:

```
mainfo/01/streets/streets.shp
mainfo/02/streets/streets.shp   #empty files
mainfo/03/streets/streets.shp
...
```

I want to use a function that will take as first parameter the first normal file from the upper folder (normal files) and as second the corresponding from the other folder (empty files).
Based on the [-3] level folder number (ex.01,02,03,etc)

Example with a function:

```
appendfunc(first_file_from_normal_files,first_file_from_empty_files)
```

How to do this in a loop?

My code:

```
for i in mainf and j in mainfo:
    appendfunc(i,j)
```

**Update**
Correct version:

```
first = ["mainf/01/streets/streets.shp", "mainf/02/streets/streets.shp", "mainf/03/streets/streets.shp"]
second = ["mainfo/01/streets/streets.shp", "mainfo/02/streets/streets.shp", "mainfo/03/streets/streets.shp"]

final = [(f,s) for f,s in zip(first,second)]

for i , j in final:
    appendfunc(i,j)
```

An alternative to automatically put in a list all the files in a main folder with full paths?

```
first= []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mainf):
    first.append(os.path.join(dirpath,dirnames,filenames))
second = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mainfo):
    second.append(os.path.join(dirpath,dirnames,filenames))
```

Comment: What code have you written so far to solve your problem ? You should express in a more detailed way your problem (paper + pen approach). Then, coding it will be much more easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
first = ["mainf/01/streets/streets.shp", "mainf/02/streets/streets.shp", "mainf/03/streets/streets.shp"]
second = ["mainf/01/streets/streets.shp", "mainf/02/streets/streets.shp", "mainf/03/streets/streets.shp"]

final = [(f,s) for f,s in zip(first,second)]
print(final)
```

Comment: Since the subfolders are hundreads can you suggest a way to not pass them to a list manually?

Comment: @user10671234 could you elaborate more on what you want to do?

Comment: example: function(i,j) where i is the first from first folder and j is the first from the  second folder but in a loop so then takes the second with the second third with the third  and so on. Basically what you did but without the necessity to put them manually in a list first.

Comment: @user10671234 in this case you have to use the `listdir` function from the `os` module along with `zip` to load them straight from their directory e.g. `for first, second in zip(os.listdir(firstpathString), os.listdir(secondpathString))`. If this doesn't work, take a look at `os.walk` function.

Comment: I don't think he wants a string operation at all. I think he wants to use `appendfunc` to work with the files in some way.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner the OP also needs a way not to append all these subfolders manually to a list, and the only way is to read them directly using the `os` module. The OP states that in the first comment of this answer.

Comment: @VasilisG. I'm having trouble understanding him, and I think we're both guessing what OP wants to a degree. You might be right, but I read that comment as more complaining about using a list comprehension.

Comment: See the updated question to see the solution.The guy will get the credit no worries. What do you think? I can't see if it works now though.Do you understand now the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `for ... and` loop. You can loop *one* iterable in one statement, and *another* iterable in another statement. This still won't give you what you want:

```
for i in mainf:
    for j in mainfo:
        appendfunc(i,j)
```

What you probably want is something like (I'm assuming `mainf` and `mainfo` are essentially the same, except one is empty):

```
for folder_num in range(len(mainf)):
    appendfunc(mainf[folder_num], mainfo[folder_num])
```

You haven't said what `appendfunc` is supposed to do, so I'll leave that to you. I'm also assuming that, depending on how you're accessing the files, you can figure out how you might need to modify the calls to `mainf[folder_num]` and `mainfo[folder_num]` (eg. you may need to inject the number back into the directory structure somehow (`mainf/{}/streets/streets.shp".format(zero_padded(folder_num))`).

Comment: appendfunc just appends whatever is in the normal file to the empty file. for every single file. And yes these two main folders are essentially the same with the difference that the one has normal files and other has files that are 0 mb (empty).Will this do what I describe?

Comment: @user10671234 Try it and see. If `appendfunc` is correct then I think it will, though I don't know the contents of `mainf` and `mainfo` so I can't be 100% sure. You might want to add a check that `len(mainf) == len(mainfo)` just so nothing weird happens.

Comment: The contents of the files are described in the question (grey blocks).Also some os.walk operation may be needed because there are many subfolders if you see the directories in the question.